# How to save a textbox as a pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, encoding, textbox

I am trying to save a textbox text as a pdf file
I have tried the following:

```
 from tkinter import *
 from tkinter import ttk
 from tkinter import filedialog
 from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
 from tkinter.filedialog import * 
 from fpdf import FPDF

def export(self):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font("Arial", size=15)
    pdf.cell(40, 10, self.agreemanttext.get("1.0", END).strip())
    pdf.output(asksaveasfilename(filetypes=[("PDF file", "*.pdf")]), "F")


def agreemnttext(self):
    self.buying_agreementsample_cash ="""text"""
    self.agreemanttextframe = Frame(self.agreemantpage, width=900, height=900)
    self.agreemanttextframe.place(x=1, y=40)
    self.agreemanttext = Text(self.agreemanttextframe, width=124, height=57)
    self.agreemanttext.pack()
    self.agreemanttext.tag_configure('tag-center', justify='right')
    self.agreemanttext.insert('end', self.buying_agreementsample_cash, 'tag-center')
    self.agreemanttext.config(state='disabled')

    self.exportbutton=Button(self.agreemantpage,text="export as pdf",command=self.export)
    self.exportbutton.place(x=80,y=600)
```

but I got this error:
p = self.pages[n].encode("latin1") if PY3K else self.pages[n]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 50-54: ordinal not in range(256)

Comment: There seems to be several questions and answers related to fpdf and encoding errors. Have you looked through them?

Comment: @BryanOakley of course, I have searched this for 4 days, and I figured that the problem is with the encoding, but I don't have any experience in text formatting and encoding or decoding, so if you can help I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the PDF specification (ISO 32000), you will find that PDF expects 14 fonts to always be present in compliant software.

These fonts are:

- Courier
- Courier-Bold
- Courier-Bold-Oblique
- Courier-Oblique
- Helvetica
- Helvetica-Bold
- Helvetica-Bold-Oblique
- Helvetica-Oblique
- Symbol
- Times-Bold
- Times-Bold-Italic
- Times-Italic
- Times-Roman
- ZapfDingbats

The characters you can display in a given font depends on the font itself. For example, there are no Arabic characters in Helvetica. Trying to display Arabic using Helvetica will not work.

All of these fonts only encode western characters. Which means they encode only a given range of unicode codepoints.

This is what is giving you the aforementioned error. The forms allows people to enter random input (including non-western characters) which can no longer be displayed in the standard 14 fonts.

Possible solution(s):

- throw away anything you can not represent
- decide on a font in an intelligent way
- use one of the google Noto fonts to ensure it can encode whatever the user throws at it (Noto stands for "No Tofu", which is nerd-talk for "those boxes you see whenever something is trying to represent a character that is out of range")